# Problems with barplot labels and time formats

Tags: r, datetime, bar-chart

I have data from multiple dive sequences of whales, and I want to plot these dive profiles when whales surface with or without small calves, so it is a horizontal barplot with spikes both ways. I am having problems customizing the axes and axis labels. In the data frame included below you will the column 'secs', which gives the y axis, and which has been converted from the column 'Time'. The column time is in the time format H:M:S, but I want the format H:M with 30 min intervals on the y axis.

On the x axis I have plotted to column 'plot', which gives seconds, where dive durations are negative if they surface without a calf, and positive if they surface with a calf. I need the dive durations to be in the format M:S, with 30 sec or 1 min intervals, and positive numbers both ways.

This version of the plot script is made based on advise below, but it doesn't work and I need some help to find out why:

```
# Convert 'secs' column to POSIXct format
dframe$secs <- as.POSIXct(dframe$secs, format = "%H:%M:%S",origin = "1992-10-22 00:00", tz = "UTC")

# Define breaks and labels for y-axis (time)
y_breaks <- seq(min(dframe$secs), max(dframe$secs), by = "30 min")

# Define breaks and labels for x-axis (dive durations)
x_breaks <- seq(-max(abs(dframe$plot)), max(abs(dframe$plot)), by = 60)

# Create barplot
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
par(mar=c(4, 4, 3.5, 1.2) + 1)

barplot(dframe$plot ~ dframe$secs, horiz = TRUE, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", 
        xlim = c(-max(abs(dframe$plot)), max(abs(dframe$plot))), 
        ylim = c(min(dframe$secs), max(dframe$secs)), xlab = "Dive Durations",cex.lab=1.5, 
        ylab = "Time of day", yaxp = c(min(dframe$secs), max(dframe$secs), length.out = length(y_breaks)), 
        xaxp = c(-max(abs(dframe$plot)), max(abs(dframe$plot)), length.out = length(x_breaks)), yaxs = "i", xaxs = "i")
mtext('WITH', side=3, line=-1, at=-300,adj=0,cex=1.6)
mtext('WITHOUT', side=3, line=-1, at=150,adj=0,cex=1.6)
```

Any help appreciated.

```
dput(dframe)
structure(list(Time = c("09:55:40", "09:55:59", "09:59:51", "10:00:05", 
"10:00:19", "10:00:39", "10:03:57", "10:04:14", "10:04:29", "10:04:43", 
"10:05:03", "10:05:29", "10:05:45", "10:11:17", "10:11:35", "10:11:45", 
"10:11:57", "10:12:14", "10:12:55", "10:13:18", "10:13:34", "10:13:52", 
"10:14:08", "10:14:26", "10:14:47", "10:15:12", "10:19:59", "10:20:14", 
"10:20:24", "10:20:38", "10:20:49", "10:21:01", "10:21:24", "10:21:38", 
"10:21:57", "10:22:18", "10:28:10", "10:28:19", "10:28:34", "10:28:42", 
"10:28:53", "10:29:07", "10:29:18", "10:29:30", "10:33:08", "10:33:20", 
"10:33:31", "10:33:42", "10:33:51", "10:34:04", "10:34:16", "10:38:10", 
"10:38:25", "10:38:33", "10:38:45", "10:38:57", "10:39:13", "10:39:30", 
"10:39:46", "10:40:01", "10:40:13", "10:40:29", "10:44:06", "10:44:18", 
"10:44:27", "10:44:38", "10:44:49", "10:44:59", "10:45:14", "10:45:27", 
"10:45:40", "10:45:58", "10:46:10", "10:49:23", "10:50:31", "10:50:44", 
"10:50:58", "10:51:11", "10:53:22", "10:53:37", "10:53:52", "10:54:07", 
"10:54:19", "10:58:26", "10:58:39", "10:58:55", "10:59:00", "10:59:12", 
"10:59:27", "10:59:48", "11:00:01", "11:04:05", "11:04:16", "11:04:30", 
"11:04:42", "11:04:54", "11:05:08", "11:05:22", "11:05:36", "11:08:43", 
"11:08:57", "11:09:09", "11:09:22", "11:09:47", "11:10:12", "11:10:35", 
"11:10:55", "11:11:19", "11:13:27", "11:13:43", "11:14:00", "11:14:15", 
"11:15:43", "11:16:02", "11:19:26", "11:19:45", "11:19:56", "11:20:07", 
"11:20:18", "11:20:37", "11:23:58", "11:24:10", "11:24:22", "11:24:36", 
"11:24:49", "11:25:02", "11:25:33", "11:29:07", "11:29:18", "11:29:30", 
"11:29:42", "11:30:10", "11:30:25", "11:34:42", "11:34:52", "11:35:04", 
"11:35:15", "11:35:26", "11:35:37", "11:35:52", "11:36:05", "11:36:16", 
"11:38:58", "11:41:05", "11:41:16", "11:41:26", "11:41:35", "11:41:46", 
"11:41:57", "11:42:08", "11:42:22", "11:42:36", "11:42:46", "11:47:20", 
"11:47:32", "11:47:58", "11:48:21", "11:48:35", "11:48:53", "11:49:03", 
"11:49:14", "11:49:33", "11:49:57", "11:50:24", "11:50:46", "11:51:10", 
"11:51:35", "11:52:05", "11:52:19", "11:55:06", "11:55:18", "11:55:30", 
"11:55:43", "11:56:01", "11:56:42", "11:56:55", "11:59:48", "12:01:10", 
"12:01:31", "12:01:45", "12:03:55", "12:04:27", "12:05:28", "12:05:58", 
"12:06:27", "12:07:51", "12:08:49", "12:09:20", "12:09:40", "12:10:03", 
"12:10:40", "12:10:55", "12:11:17", "12:11:37", "12:12:17", "12:14:34", 
"12:15:04", "12:15:17", "12:15:46", "12:16:01", "12:16:25", "12:16:37", 
"12:16:59", "12:17:17", "12:21:01", "12:21:22", "12:21:30", "12:21:48", 
"12:22:12", "12:22:29", "12:22:55", "12:23:15", "12:23:26", "12:23:53", 
"12:27:39", "12:27:58", "12:28:17", "12:28:38", "12:28:56", "12:29:17", 
"12:30:15", "12:30:48", "12:31:47", "12:32:22", "12:33:36", "12:33:57", 
"12:34:56", "12:36:58", "12:37:04", "12:38:00", "12:38:20", "12:38:36", 
"12:38:53", "12:39:17", "12:39:32", "12:39:47", "12:40:08", "12:40:27", 
"12:43:45", "12:43:54", "12:44:02", "12:44:12", "12:44:23", "12:44:38", 
"12:44:55", "12:45:12", "12:45:26", "12:45:49", "12:48:11", "12:48:24", 
"12:50:20", "12:51:27", "12:51:37", "12:51:47", "12:52:16", "12:52:26", 
"12:55:16", "12:55:29", "12:55:39", "12:55:51", "12:56:01", "12:56:13", 
"12:59:52", "13:00:07", "13:00:20", "13:00:33", "13:00:43", "13:00:56", 
"13:01:05", "13:04:31", "13:04:44", "13:04:54", "13:05:06", "13:05:21", 
"13:05:39", "13:05:51", "13:06:05", "13:06:19", "13:06:33", "13:06:43", 
"13:06:56", "13:07:11", "13:07:24", "13:07:37", "13:07:55", "13:08:12", 
"13:08:28", "13:08:43", "13:08:58", "13:09:13", "13:09:30", "13:12:36", 
"13:12:53", "13:13:07", "13:17:07", "13:17:41", "13:18:13", "13:18:52", 
"13:19:14", "13:19:28", "13:21:22", "13:21:47", "13:22:00", "13:24:00", 
"13:24:18", "13:24:30", "13:25:23", "13:25:50", "13:27:19", "13:27:59", 
"13:28:12", "13:28:28", "13:28:55", "13:29:15", "13:29:59", "13:30:10", 
"13:32:38", "13:33:07", "13:33:20", "13:33:36", "13:37:38", "13:37:49", 
"13:38:00", "13:38:17", "13:38:27", "13:38:40", "13:38:52", "13:39:08", 
"13:39:30", "13:39:46", "13:40:09", "13:40:38", "13:40:56", "13:44:19", 
"13:44:35", "13:44:47", "13:45:02", "13:45:26", "13:45:43", "13:45:57", 
"13:49:11", "13:49:34", "13:49:57", "13:50:36", "13:51:22", "13:51:42", 
"13:51:58", "13:52:30", "13:55:52", "13:56:10", "13:56:24", "13:56:32", 
"13:56:51", "13:57:10", "13:57:42", "13:58:12", "14:01:42", "14:01:58", 
"14:02:11", "14:02:30", "14:03:04", "14:03:27", "14:03:49", "14:04:07", 
"14:04:43", "14:04:57", "14:08:01", "14:08:20", "14:08:36", "14:08:50", 
"14:09:07", "14:09:25", "14:09:46", "14:10:34", "14:14:24", "14:14:39", 
"14:15:02", "14:15:19", "14:15:42", "14:15:57", "14:16:20", "14:16:35", 
"14:19:53", "14:20:16", "14:20:31", "14:20:50", "14:21:03", "14:21:18", 
"14:24:23", "14:24:43", "14:25:02", "14:25:16", "14:27:35", "14:27:58", 
"14:28:14", "14:28:54", "14:31:38", "14:32:29", "14:32:41", "14:32:57", 
"14:33:11", "14:33:22", "14:36:33", "14:36:51", "14:37:20", "14:39:26", 
"14:39:27", "14:39:42", "14:39:53", "14:40:40", "14:40:54", "14:41:11", 
"14:41:30", "14:44:56", "14:45:11", "14:45:25", "14:45:42", "14:47:39", 
"14:47:59", "14:48:09", "14:48:21", "14:48:34", "14:49:02", "14:49:17", 
"14:49:36", "14:49:58", "14:50:09", "14:55:02", "14:55:21", "14:55:47", 
"14:56:07", "14:56:43", "14:56:57", "15:00:12", "15:00:32", "15:00:52", 
"15:01:24", "15:01:50", "15:02:45", "15:02:56", "15:03:26", "15:05:58", 
"15:06:05", "15:06:20", "15:06:38", "15:06:51", "15:07:13", "15:07:34", 
"15:07:55", "15:08:20", "15:08:40", "15:10:42", "15:10:55", "15:11:13", 
"15:11:26", "15:15:07", "15:15:20", "15:15:34", "15:15:54", "15:16:01", 
"15:16:14", "15:16:32", "15:16:48", "15:18:43", "15:18:58", "15:19:11", 
"15:19:49", "15:20:15", "15:21:34", "15:21:47", "15:22:04", "15:22:11", 
"15:22:25", "15:22:45", "15:23:03", "15:23:18", "15:23:36", "15:26:30", 
"15:26:45", "15:26:59", "15:27:15", "15:27:27", "15:27:44", "15:28:30", 
"15:28:41", "15:31:06", "15:33:49", "15:34:13", "15:34:33", "15:37:32", 
"15:37:59", "15:38:17", "15:38:32", "15:38:47", "15:39:08", "15:39:56", 
"15:40:08", "15:40:24", "15:40:35", "15:43:14", "15:43:33", "15:43:48", 
"15:44:09", "15:44:59", "15:45:25", "15:46:08", "15:46:28", "15:47:47", 
"15:48:02", "15:48:29"), Kat = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), secs = c(35740L, 
35759L, 35991L, 36005L, 36019L, 36039L, 36237L, 36254L, 36269L, 
36283L, 36303L, 36329L, 36345L, 36677L, 36695L, 36705L, 36717L, 
36734L, 36775L, 36798L, 36814L, 36832L, 36848L, 36866L, 36887L, 
36912L, 37199L, 37214L, 37224L, 37238L, 37249L, 37261L, 37284L, 
37298L, 37317L, 37338L, 37690L, 37699L, 37714L, 37722L, 37733L, 
37747L, 37758L, 37770L, 37988L, 38000L, 38011L, 38022L, 38031L, 
38044L, 38056L, 38290L, 38305L, 38313L, 38325L, 38337L, 38353L, 
38370L, 38386L, 38401L, 38413L, 38429L, 38646L, 38658L, 38667L, 
38678L, 38689L, 38699L, 38714L, 38727L, 38740L, 38758L, 38770L, 
38963L, 39031L, 39044L, 39058L, 39071L, 39202L, 39217L, 39232L, 
39247L, 39259L, 39506L, 39519L, 39535L, 39540L, 39552L, 39567L, 
39588L, 39601L, 39845L, 39856L, 39870L, 39882L, 39894L, 39908L, 
39922L, 39936L, 40123L, 40137L, 40149L, 40162L, 40187L, 40212L, 
40235L, 40255L, 40279L, 40407L, 40423L, 40440L, 40455L, 40543L, 
40562L, 40766L, 40785L, 40796L, 40807L, 40818L, 40837L, 41038L, 
41050L, 41062L, 41076L, 41089L, 41102L, 41133L, 41347L, 41358L, 
41370L, 41382L, 41410L, 41425L, 41682L, 41692L, 41704L, 41715L, 
41726L, 41737L, 41752L, 41765L, 41776L, 41938L, 42065L, 42076L, 
42086L, 42095L, 42106L, 42117L, 42128L, 42142L, 42156L, 42166L, 
42440L, 42452L, 42478L, 42501L, 42515L, 42533L, 42543L, 42554L, 
42573L, 42597L, 42624L, 42646L, 42670L, 42695L, 42725L, 42739L, 
42906L, 42918L, 42930L, 42943L, 42961L, 43002L, 43015L, 43188L, 
43270L, 43291L, 43305L, 43435L, 43467L, 43528L, 43558L, 43587L, 
43671L, 43729L, 43760L, 43780L, 43803L, 43840L, 43855L, 43877L, 
43897L, 43937L, 44074L, 44104L, 44117L, 44146L, 44161L, 44185L, 
44197L, 44219L, 44237L, 44461L, 44482L, 44490L, 44508L, 44532L, 
44549L, 44575L, 44595L, 44606L, 44633L, 44859L, 44878L, 44897L, 
44918L, 44936L, 44957L, 45015L, 45048L, 45107L, 45142L, 45216L, 
45237L, 45296L, 45418L, 45424L, 45480L, 45500L, 45516L, 45533L, 
45557L, 45572L, 45587L, 45608L, 45627L, 45825L, 45834L, 45842L, 
45852L, 45863L, 45878L, 45895L, 45912L, 45926L, 45949L, 46091L, 
46104L, 46220L, 46287L, 46297L, 46307L, 46336L, 46346L, 46516L, 
46529L, 46539L, 46551L, 46561L, 46573L, 46792L, 46807L, 46820L, 
46833L, 46843L, 46856L, 46865L, 47071L, 47084L, 47094L, 47106L, 
47121L, 47139L, 47151L, 47165L, 47179L, 47193L, 47203L, 47216L, 
47231L, 47244L, 47257L, 47275L, 47292L, 47308L, 47323L, 47338L, 
47353L, 47370L, 47556L, 47573L, 47587L, 47827L, 47861L, 47893L, 
47932L, 47954L, 47968L, 48082L, 48107L, 48120L, 48240L, 48258L, 
48270L, 48323L, 48350L, 48439L, 48479L, 48492L, 48508L, 48535L, 
48555L, 48599L, 48610L, 48758L, 48787L, 48800L, 48816L, 49058L, 
49069L, 49080L, 49097L, 49107L, 49120L, 49132L, 49148L, 49170L, 
49186L, 49209L, 49238L, 49256L, 49459L, 49475L, 49487L, 49502L, 
49526L, 49543L, 49557L, 49751L, 49774L, 49797L, 49836L, 49882L, 
49902L, 49918L, 49950L, 50152L, 50170L, 50184L, 50192L, 50211L, 
50230L, 50262L, 50292L, 50502L, 50518L, 50531L, 50550L, 50584L, 
50607L, 50629L, 50647L, 50683L, 50697L, 50881L, 50900L, 50916L, 
50930L, 50947L, 50965L, 50986L, 51034L, 51264L, 51279L, 51302L, 
51319L, 51342L, 51357L, 51380L, 51395L, 51593L, 51616L, 51631L, 
51650L, 51663L, 51678L, 51863L, 51883L, 51902L, 51916L, 52055L, 
52078L, 52094L, 52134L, 52298L, 52349L, 52361L, 52377L, 52391L, 
52402L, 52593L, 52611L, 52640L, 52766L, 52767L, 52782L, 52793L, 
52840L, 52854L, 52871L, 52890L, 53096L, 53111L, 53125L, 53142L, 
53259L, 53279L, 53289L, 53301L, 53314L, 53342L, 53357L, 53376L, 
53398L, 53409L, 53702L, 53721L, 53747L, 53767L, 53803L, 53817L, 
54012L, 54032L, 54052L, 54084L, 54110L, 54165L, 54176L, 54206L, 
54358L, 54365L, 54380L, 54398L, 54411L, 54433L, 54454L, 54475L, 
54500L, 54520L, 54642L, 54655L, 54673L, 54686L, 54907L, 54920L, 
54934L, 54954L, 54961L, 54974L, 54992L, 55008L, 55123L, 55138L, 
55151L, 55189L, 55215L, 55294L, 55307L, 55324L, 55331L, 55345L, 
55365L, 55383L, 55398L, 55416L, 55590L, 55605L, 55619L, 55635L, 
55647L, 55664L, 55710L, 55721L, 55866L, 56029L, 56053L, 56073L, 
56252L, 56279L, 56297L, 56312L, 56327L, 56348L, 56396L, 56408L, 
56424L, 56435L, 56594L, 56613L, 56628L, 56649L, 56699L, 56725L, 
56768L, 56788L, 56867L, 56882L, 56909L), dif = c(17, 19, 232, 
14, 14, 20, 198, 17, 15, 14, 20, 26, 16, 332, 18, 10, 12, 17, 
41, 23, 16, 18, 16, 18, 21, 25, 287, 15, 10, 14, 11, 12, 23, 
14, 19, 21, 352, 9, 15, 8, 11, 14, 11, 12, 218, 12, 11, 11, 9, 
13, 12, 234, 15, 8, 12, 12, 16, 17, 16, 15, 12, 16, 217, 12, 
9, 11, 11, 10, 15, 13, 13, 18, 12, 193, 68, 13, 14, 13, 131, 
15, 15, 15, 12, 247, 13, 16, 5, 12, 15, 21, 13, 244, 11, 14, 
12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 187, 14, 12, 13, 25, 25, 23, 20, 24, 128, 
16, 17, 15, 88, 19, 204, 19, 11, 11, 11, 19, 201, 12, 12, 14, 
13, 13, 31, 214, 11, 12, 12, 28, 15, 257, 10, 12, 11, 11, 11, 
15, 13, 11, 162, 127, 11, 10, 9, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 10, 274, 
12, 26, 23, 14, 18, 10, 11, 19, 24, 27, 22, 24, 25, 30, 14, 167, 
12, 12, 13, 18, 41, 13, 173, 82, 21, 14, 130, 32, 61, 30, 29, 
84, 58, 31, 20, 23, 37, 15, 22, 20, 40, 137, 30, 13, 29, 15, 
24, 12, 22, 18, 224, 21, 8, 18, 24, 17, 26, 20, 11, 27, 226, 
19, 19, 21, 18, 21, 58, 33, 59, 35, 74, 21, 59, 122, 6, 56, 20, 
16, 17, 24, 15, 15, 21, 19, 198, 9, 8, 10, 11, 15, 17, 17, 14, 
23, 142, 13, 116, 67, 10, 10, 29, 10, 170, 13, 10, 12, 10, 12, 
219, 15, 13, 13, 10, 13, 9, 206, 13, 10, 12, 15, 18, 12, 14, 
14, 14, 10, 13, 15, 13, 13, 18, 17, 16, 15, 15, 15, 17, 186, 
17, 14, 240, 34, 32, 39, 22, 14, 114, 25, 13, 120, 18, 12, 53, 
27, 89, 40, 13, 16, 27, 20, 44, 11, 148, 29, 13, 16, 242, 11, 
11, 17, 10, 13, 12, 16, 22, 16, 23, 29, 18, 203, 16, 12, 15, 
24, 17, 14, 194, 23, 23, 39, 46, 20, 16, 32, 202, 18, 14, 8, 
19, 19, 32, 30, 210, 16, 13, 19, 34, 23, 22, 18, 36, 14, 184, 
19, 16, 14, 17, 18, 21, 48, 230, 15, 23, 17, 23, 15, 23, 15, 
198, 23, 15, 19, 13, 15, 185, 20, 19, 14, 139, 23, 16, 40, 164, 
51, 12, 16, 14, 11, 191, 18, 29, 126, 1, 15, 11, 47, 14, 17, 
19, 206, 15, 14, 17, 117, 20, 10, 12, 13, 28, 15, 19, 22, 11, 
293, 19, 26, 20, 36, 14, 195, 20, 20, 32, 26, 55, 11, 30, 152, 
7, 15, 18, 13, 22, 21, 21, 25, 20, 122, 13, 18, 13, 221, 13, 
14, 20, 7, 13, 18, 16, 115, 15, 13, 38, 26, 79, 13, 17, 7, 14, 
20, 18, 15, 18, 174, 15, 14, 16, 12, 17, 46, 11, 145, 163, 24, 
20, 179, 27, 18, 15, 15, 21, 48, 12, 16, 11, 159, 19, 15, 21, 
50, 26, 43, 20, 79, 15, 27), plot = c(17L, 19L, 232L, 14L, 14L, 
20L, 198L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 16L, 332L, 18L, 10L, 12L, 
-17L, -41L, -23L, -16L, -18L, -16L, -18L, -21L, -25L, 287L, 15L, 
10L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 23L, 14L, 19L, 21L, 352L, 9L, 15L, 8L, -11L, 
14L, 11L, -12L, 218L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 234L, 15L, 
8L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 16L, 217L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 
11L, 10L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 12L, 193L, 68L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 
131L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 247L, 13L, 16L, 5L, 12L, 15L, 21L, 
13L, 244L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, -187L, 14L, -12L, 
13L, -25L, -25L, -23L, -20L, -24L, 128L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 88L, 
19L, 204L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 201L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 
13L, 31L, 214L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 28L, 15L, 257L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 15L, 13L, 11L, -162L, 127L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 14L, -14L, 10L, 274L, 12L, 26L, 23L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 11L, 
19L, 24L, 27L, 22L, 24L, -25L, -30L, -14L, -167L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
18L, 41L, 13L, 173L, 82L, 21L, 14L, 130L, 32L, 61L, 30L, 29L, 
84L, 58L, 31L, 20L, -23L, 37L, 15L, -22L, -20L, -40L, -137L, 
30L, 13L, 29L, 15L, 24L, 12L, 22L, 18L, 224L, 21L, 8L, 18L, 24L, 
17L, 26L, 20L, 11L, -27L, 226L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 18L, 21L, 58L, 
33L, 59L, 35L, 74L, 21L, 59L, -122L, -6L, -56L, -20L, -16L, -17L, 
-24L, -15L, -15L, -21L, 19L, -198L, -9L, -8L, -10L, -11L, -15L, 
-17L, -17L, -14L, -23L, -142L, -13L, -116L, 67L, -10L, -10L, 
-29L, -10L, -170L, -13L, -10L, -12L, -10L, -12L, 219L, 15L, -13L, 
13L, 10L, 13L, -9L, 206L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 12L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
17L, 186L, 17L, 14L, 240L, 34L, 32L, 39L, 22L, 14L, 114L, 25L, 
13L, 120L, 18L, 12L, 53L, 27L, 89L, 40L, 13L, 16L, 27L, 20L, 
44L, 11L, 148L, 29L, 13L, 16L, 242L, 11L, 11L, 17L, 10L, 13L, 
12L, 16L, 22L, 16L, 23L, 29L, 18L, 203L, 16L, 12L, 15L, 24L, 
17L, 14L, 194L, 23L, 23L, 39L, 46L, 20L, 16L, 32L, 202L, 18L, 
14L, 8L, 19L, 19L, -32L, -30L, 210L, 16L, 13L, 19L, 34L, 23L, 
22L, 18L, 36L, 14L, 184L, 19L, 16L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 48L, 
230L, 15L, 23L, 17L, 23L, 15L, 23L, 15L, 198L, 23L, 15L, 19L, 
13L, 15L, 185L, 20L, 19L, 14L, 139L, 23L, 16L, -40L, 164L, 51L, 
12L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 191L, 18L, 29L, 126L, 1L, 15L, 11L, 47L, 
14L, 17L, 19L, 206L, 15L, 14L, 17L, 117L, 20L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 
28L, 15L, 19L, 22L, 11L, 293L, 19L, 26L, 20L, 36L, 14L, 195L, 
20L, 20L, 32L, -26L, 55L, -11L, -30L, -152L, -7L, 15L, -18L, 
-13L, -22L, -21L, -21L, -25L, -20L, -122L, -13L, -18L, -13L, 
-221L, -13L, -14L, -20L, 7L, -13L, -18L, -16L, -115L, -15L, -13L, 
-38L, -26L, -79L, -13L, -17L, -7L, -14L, -20L, -18L, -15L, -18L, 
-174L, -15L, -14L, -16L, -12L, -17L, -46L, -11L, -145L, -163L, 
-24L, -20L, 179L, 27L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 21L, 48L, 12L, 16L, 11L, 
159L, 19L, 15L, 21L, 50L, 26L, 43L, 20L, 79L, 15L, 27L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 3:512)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Convert 'secs' column to POSIXct format
dframe$secs <- as.POSIXct(dframe$secs, format = "%H:%M:%S")

# Define breaks and labels for y-axis (time)
y_breaks <- seq(min(dframe$secs), max(dframe$secs), by = "30 min")

# Define breaks and labels for x-axis (dive durations)
x_breaks <- seq(-max(abs(dframe$plot)), max(abs(dframe$plot)), by = 60)

# Create barplot
barplot(dframe$plot ~ dframe$secs, horiz = TRUE, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlim = c(-max(abs(dframe$plot)), max(abs(dframe$plot))), ylim = c(min(dframe$secs), max(dframe$secs)), xlab = "Dive Durations", ylab = "Time", yaxp = c(min(dframe$secs), max(dframe$secs), length.out = length(y_breaks)), xaxp = c(-max(abs(dframe$plot)), max(abs(dframe$plot)), length.out = length(x_breaks)), yaxs = "i", xaxs = "i")
```

Comment: WHen running the first line I get the following error message: Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(dframe$secs, format = "%H:%M:%S") : 
  'origin' must be supplied

Comment: for instance if dframe$secs represents elapsed time from midnight, you can specify origin as follows:
dframe$secs <- as.POSIXct(dframe$secs, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

Comment: Thanks. That works. But, I also get an error message when running your second line (y_breaks): Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number